# Using Vuetify with Jhipster

Tags: vuetify.js, jhipster

Is there anyone who successfully integrate Vuetify and its theme with JHipster? I am still trying to integrate but still not happening. I have projects using vuetify but we want to move the base using Jhipster, when it comes to default frontend, I am stuck at integrating my current vuetify implementation.

Would like to have suggestion and guide on using vuetify with JHipster. Tia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used webpack installation for it. [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#webpack-install)

From main project file location, install vuetify

```
npm install vuetify
npm install sass@~1.32 sass-loader deepmerge -D
```

1. You need to create a file that named webpack.config.js 
   [image: webpack.config.js]

Inside of it:

```
    // webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              fiber: require('fibers'),
              indentedSyntax: true // optional
            },
            // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              sassOptions: {
                fiber: require('fibers'),
                indentedSyntax: true // optional
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
```

2. Create a file plugins/vuetify.js

```
    // src/plugins/vuetify.js
    
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
    import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
    
    
    Vue.use(Vuetify)
    
    const opts = {}
    
    export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

3. Add vuetify to main.ts or main.js

```
// vuetify-import
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export
.
.
.
new Vue({
  vuetify,
```

4. index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
  <!-- Vuetify icons -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
```

5. app.vue
   Dont forget to change divs to v-app.

```html
<template>
      <v-app id="app">
        <ribbon></ribbon>
        <div id="app-header">
          <jhi-navbar></jhi-navbar>
        </div>
        <div  >
          <router-view></router-view>
    
          <b-modal id="login-page" hide-footer lazy>
            <span data-cy="loginTitle" slot="modal-title" id="login-title" v-text="$t('login.title')">Sign in</span>
            <login-form></login-form>
          </b-modal>
           <jhi-footer></jhi-footer>
        </div>
    
        
      </v-app>
      
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts" src="./app.component.ts"></script>
```

Key points

- You have to be sure about location of plugins/vuetify.js file .
- Dont forget to add v-app tags.
- Dont be afraid of create files.

This is my solution. But if you have a ready-made project, the project view might look different bcx of vuetify.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, i just flagged the answer as the correct answer.